# How to get only digits between two strings with regex?

Tags: regex

We have urls in the following URL formats, I want to get only **digit** values between the strings I specified, I tried a pattern like this `(?<=\/sub.example.com\/)(.*)(?=\?[Uu]rl|$)` but it does not give the result I want

```
https://sub.example.com/79084/t/64931?Url=https%3a%2f%2fwww.test.com%2fpath%2fotherpath%2f
https://sub.example.com/79084/t/64931
```

Expected results:
`[ 79084, 64931 ]`

I need to exclude `/t/`

https://regexr.com/6ti8p

Comment: Do you want `[ 79084, 64931 ]` to be matched in both the inputs?

Comment: yep I need to filter `/t/`part from result @anubhava

Comment: `/t/` could be anything with any length, but it will be always between slashes

Comment: Do you need to just get the values from the url, or do you need to **validate the url**? If it's just the first option (apparently from your expected results), why not just something like `\/(\d+)\b`? That captures both numbers (you need to get the groups from the results).

Comment: thanks to everyone who answered the question till now, I wish I could choose everyone's answer as correct, but since I didn't have such a chance, I will choose the correct answer of the first interested person, please don't get me wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dynamic length lookbehind feature in Javascript, you can use this regex:

```bash
(?<=\/sub\.example\.com\/(?:[^\/]*\/)*)\d+(?=(?:\/[^\/]*)*(?:\?[Uu]rl|$))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regexr.com/6tia0)

Note that it will match all the digits after domain name e.g. `https://sub.example.com/79084/t/64931/1234/6789` will have 4 matches for all the numbers.

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?<=\/sub\.example\.com\/(?:[^\/]*\/)*)`: Lookbehind to assert presence of `sub.example.com/` followed by 0 or more repeats of path components separated with `/`
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `(?=(?:\/[^\/]*)*(?:\?[Uu]rl|$))`: Must be followed by 0 or more repeats of path components separated with `/` and that must be followed by `?Url` or line end.

Comment: Note that this requires a regex engine that supports variable-width lookbehind patterns, and there are not a lot of such regex engines.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, yes I am aware of the situation you are talking about, but we do not have such a problem

Answer (score 2):

Given the sample URLs in the question it should be sufficient to simply match digits preceded by a slash:

```
(?<=/)\d+
```

Demo: https://regexr.com/6tia6

Comment: This will give incorrect matches if `/<digits>` is after `Url` such as `https://sub.example.com/79084/t/64931?Url=a/1234` will match `1234` also or `https://notamatch.com/79084/t/64931?Url=a/1234`

Answer (score 1):

If all your Urls have this same format with `digits + /anything/ + digits`, then you can change your `.*` to be more specific:

```
(?<=\/sub.example.com\/)(\d+)\/(.*)\/(\d+)(?=\?[Uu]rl|$)
```

So changing it to `(\d+)\/(.*)\/(\d+)` allows you to get each set of digits as a matched group.

https://regex101.com/r/dv7BEv/2